# How to access server root with netatalk / AFP?

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

I've installed and configured netatalk successfully. However I'm not able to get access my root directory.

I've tried this in /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default :

```
/ ROOTVOL allow:root,@root options:usedots,upriv
```

But is seems like root user is not allowed.

I've also tried :

```
/ ROOTVOL allow:maarten,@maarten options:usedots,upriv
```

This way I can mount the volume as user "maarten", but of course I won't
have the permissions to read/write.

How can I get access to all my files (as root user) through AFP ?